# Integrating RHEL and Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, rhel

I'm integrating RHEL 6.5 server and Windows Server 2008 R2 (Active Directory) for authentication. i.e Clients are able to login into RHEL serve using user details in AD.

I followed same procedure(Configuration 3)
http://www.redhat.com/en/files/resources/en-rhel-intergrating-rhel-6-active-directory.pdf and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEhz5ZVfYJI&index=16&list=WL

I configured same and it was not working as expected.

I'm getting a error like

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server not found in Kerberos database

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server not found in Kerberos database

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
```

Could you help me on this?

Comment: can you give the contents of your /etc/krb5.conf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Microsoft TechNet's Troubleshooting Tips](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463167.aspx):

> DNS-related Error Messages
>
> Investigate DNS issues if you are experiencing error messages similar
>   to those listed as follows:
>
> - Host name cannot be canonicalized.
> - Incorrect net address.
> - Server not found in Kerberos database.
> - Cannot contact KDC for requested realm.

In me case the issue was that I had to use the FQDN, which is required by Kerberos. Not using a FQDN got me the same error, "Server not found in Kerberos database".

Also it's a good idea to double check that the DNS is resolving correctly and the server is reachable.